# Wordpress URL behind nginx reverse

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, wordpress

I have  WordPress instances on apache2 in a internal server (Debian).

I reach these instances via a nginx reverse proxy.

Reverse it's ok for the WP front page but all links in pages refers to the internal server (ex : 192.168.42.42/wp2/...) instead of the reverse's url.
I have this problem only with WP : I also have limesurvey and dolibarr instances and no problems with it.

In WP I can change the "Site Adress (URL)" settings but I search an other way to do that with the reverse.

I try a lot of things but nothing works.

My actually nginx conf :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mondomaine.fr;
        location / {
            proxy_pass      http://internal-server/;
            }

        location /wp2/ {
            proxy_pass      http://internal-server/wp2/;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your urls should be only domain name not IP's. This can be tricky to fix retroactively.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the Home and Site URL settings in the WordPress configuration (see [this document](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL)) are shown written in full with *scheme*, *hostname*, and *path*, e.g. `http://192.168.42.42/wp2/`.

If you remove the *scheme* and *hostname*, your pages will be populated with relative-URLs and the browser will assume the *scheme* and *hostname* of the reverse proxy. For example, use: `/wp2/`